# Are the loadComponent, loadHelper and loadModel methods in cakephp examples of Dependency injection?

Tags: cakephp, dependency-injection

The title says it:
Are the loadComponent, loadHelper and loadModel methods in cakephp examples of Dependency injection?

Other

Answer (score 1):

No, they are [locators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern). They'll basically resolve a simple string name to a class in a specific namespace.

Taken from the linked page:

> The service locator pattern is a design pattern used in software development to encapsulate the processes involved in obtaining a service with a strong abstraction layer. This pattern uses a central registry known as the "service locator", which on request returns the information necessary to perform a certain task.

Read the linked page for more details.